# Making a Pure CSS Dock

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, dock

After playing with CSS 3, I had the crazy idea to make an OS X-style dock with it (a DIV container with elements inside it, which, using the CSS :hover subclass, increase in size upon mouseover). However, I'm running into some strange effects when implementing it. So far, this is what I've tried:

### Code

---

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    margin:0;
}
.dockHolder{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
}
.dock{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.dockItem{
    height:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    text-align:center;

    transition-property:width, height;
    -o-transition-property:width, height;
    -moz-transition-property:width, height;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, height;
    transition-duration:.25s;
    -o-transition-duration:.25s;
    -moz-transition-duration:.25s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.25s;
    transition-timing-function:linear;
    -o-transition-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;
}
.dockItem:hover{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dockHolder" style="height:64px;max-height:64px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="dock" style="background-color:lightgray;">
        <center>
            <div class="dockItem" style="background-color:magenta;"><img height="100%" src="pony.png" /></div>
            <div class="dockItem" style="background-color:magenta;"><img height="100%" src="bhs256.png" /></div>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My test page is at <del>http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/testAnims.htm</del>(died with Opera Unite) if you wanna see what I have so far.

### Missing functionality

---

**Unexpected effects** include:

- Inability to place the `dock` element at the bottom of the `dockHolder` element
- `dockItem` element not expanding width-wise along with its child image
- `dockItem` and `dock` elements will not center inside the `dockHolder` container with CSS (tried `margin:auto;`, `box-pack:center;`, `box-align:center;`, etc.); only the `<center>` HTML tag works
- In Opera and Firefox (I've given up on IE), `dockItem`s are extremely wide

**Intended effects** that are not present include:

- `dockItem`s stay within the `dock` element until resizing, at which time they increase proportionally to the size of the `dockHolder` element, but the `dock` element stays the same size
- The `dock` element is constantly only wide enough to contain all the `dockItem`s within it, and never wider not shorter than the combined widths of all `dockItem`s and their margins.

### Question

---

**Does anyone have a solution that will fix the unexpected effects andor implement the absent intended effects?**

### Final implementation

---

Below is the code of my final solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body{
    margin:0;
}
.dockHolder {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 128px;
    line-height: 128px;
}

.dock {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    background:
        -o-linear-gradient(top, #AAA 0, #CCC 49%, #AAA 51%, #808080 100%);
    background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(top, #AAA 0, #CCC 49%, #AAA 51%, #808080 100%);
    background:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #AAA 0, #CCC 49%, #AAA 51%, #808080 100%);
    border: 1px solid gray;
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0 8px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.dockItem {
    display: inline;
    height: 50%;
    vertical-align: bottom;

    transition-property:width, height;
    -o-transition-property:width, height;
    -ms-transition-property:width, height;
    -moz-transition-property:width, height;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, height;
    transition-duration:.25s;
    -o-transition-duration:.25s;
    -ms-transition-duration:.25s;
    -moz-transition-duration:.25s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.25s;
    transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}
.dockItem:hover {
    height: 100%;
}
.dockItem:active {
    vertical-align:top;
    height:95%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dockHolder" style="height:128px;line-height:128px;">
        <span class="dock">
            <img class="dockItem" src="pony.png"/>
            <img class="dockItem" src="bhs256.png"/>
            <img class="dockItem" src="mcgrass.png"/>
        </span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Working example (might go out of date): <del>http://admin.s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/testDock.html</del> (died with Opera Unite)

Comment: I KNOW. Keep reading; I tried CSS centering

Comment: Why are you using both the `style` attribute *and* a CSS rule for the `.docHolder` element?

Comment: Where is the `.dock` element? I only see a `.dockHolder` and `.dockItem` elements in your HTML code.

Comment: just so I can see where the `dockHolder` is. the indended effect is that it is invisible to the end user, but that is counterproductive at this stage. I also use the `style` attribute in the `dock` so that someone using this API can choose their own dock color and height (I don't like arbitrary choices like that). I only use it in the `dockItem`s for debugging purposes.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Sorry, I must have deleted it while editing... it's the first element within the `dockHolder`, and it contains the `dockItem`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How's this?

HTML:

```
<div class="dockbg"></div>
<div class="dock">
    <img src="foo.png">
    <img src="bar.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dockbg {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 35px;
    background: #bbb;
}

.dock {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.dock img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    /* + your animation properties */
}


.dock img:hover {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/QM7M7/3/show/

Comment: @Supuhstar Why do you need both a `dock` and a `dochHolder`?

Comment: The `dock` is what the user sees as the dock (it wraps around the `dockItem`s like Mac OS X's does), whereas the `dockHolder` is what holds the `dock` and all its items, specifying the maximum size of a "zoomed-in" item

Comment: @Supuhstar I've updated my demo. It's a bit of a hack - I've placed the "dock" in the background, while a transparent dock-holder contains the icons in the foreground...

Comment: close... but unlike a dock, it always spans the width of the screen, instead of conforming to the icons. See my latest edit for my closest attempt

Comment: @ŠimeVidas  what would really, really really be awesome, is if you could make different versions of this for docking the menu on the left and on the right. Because honestly this is the best docking menu I've seen so far and most elegant... i just don't want it at the bottom and my CSS skills are not good enough to figure out how to modify yours and make it float right... :)

Answer (score 0):

- For me the problem comes from the fact that you don't specify a fixed
  width size. My idea is cancel the dockItem class , you don't need it.
  Play with an CSS img class directly.
- To center your element use    "margin : auto 0px auto 0px;".
- First of it, use a reset, it will help you to do it correctly  : http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/#comment-18168
- you should you a display:block; and float:left; than the display:inline-block;
- you should you a `<ul>` and `<li>` element to help you.

Comment: Using `float:left;` makes the dock the same size as the items and places the dock and its items in the topleft corner of the `dockHolder`, and using `display:block;` makes the items span the full width of the `dock`. Also, where and why should I use `ul` and `li`?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript and css to make the icons before and after the hovered icon a little bigger too for a  smoother animation ;)

Comment: The question is about CSS3, so the idea of using Javascript pointless, but I must agree that's a good idea